# Rename files from an Excel file

Tags: r, excel, csv, file-rename

I have the following list of files in a folder:

```
1.docx
2.docx
3.docx
4.docx
6.txt
```

I figured out how to mass rename using this code:

`file.rename(list.files(pattern="*.docx"), paste0("", 1:4,".docx"))`

I have dates in the correct order in a `csv` file that I would like to append to the end of each filename accordingly.

So **1.docx - date is cell A1**; **2.docx - date in A2**, etc. Example of final filename: `1 MMDDYY.docx` etc. What would this look like?

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the link, but I have come across that one before. I have a list of dates in a csv file that I would like to append to end of each filename (that I renamed in R) from a 1:1 matching fashion.

Comment: Perhaps this, I don't know if Stackoverflow allows for third-party software, but I use it. https://www.advancedrenamer.com/

Comment: Thank you for the resource. I am trying to develop an R code solution because I am immersing myself in R programming. However, if I cannot create one, I have an alternative :D.